.NET MAUI CommunityToolkit.Mvvm ICommand
I have a question about .NET MAUI. I'm learning from the following site: https://youtu.be/5Qga2pniN78?si=MQgeLoEsonrdci9a&t=564.
I'm having trouble with ICommand errors, even though I should have downloaded CommunityToolkit.Mvvm as per the video. As shown in the image, ICommand cannot be found within the dependency [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.dll]. Could it be because I'm using net8.0-android? The video is based on net6.0-android. If anyone knows the reason, I would appreciate your advice.
I tried to do same thing with video.

[CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.ICommand] Has been renamed To [RelayCommand]
Required Namespace : using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
Suppose you have a button action named [Button_GoToHome]
you must append [Async] on the ViewModel [.cs file] and [Command] in [.xaml file] as the following example

In your (ViewModel.cs) create button action when clicked:
[RelayCommand]
public async Task Button_GoToHomeAsync()
{
    // Your Action Here when the button is clicked
}

In your ContentPage,ContentView, ... Xaml file :
<Button Text="Go To Home" Command="{Binding Button_GoToHomeCommand}" />


Mm, I don't have a  [Button_GoToHome]....
In the video(9:10), he delete the error of ICommand by chosing  "using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;".
However, in my situation, I can't find it.
I only find "using System,Windows.Input."...
How can I fix it..?

install packages from [Manage NuGet Packages] CommunityToolkit.Maui (version 9.0.0) and CommunityToolkit.Mvvm (version 8.2.2) if you are targetting .net8

Replace [Button_GoToHome] by your button action and don't forget to add Async and Command as explained in my answer

Thank you for replying.
I installed CommunityToolkit.Maui (version 9.0.0).
Does adding  [Async]  mean that just put  "[Async]" in my ViewModel.cs?
I have just put it [Async]  in my ViewModel.cs.
However, [Async] also has a error like [ICommand]...
Error number is CS0246...

You are welcome, you must add the required namespace [using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;] on the top of ViewModel.cs file

If you still facing issues to implement that, kindly post some parts of your code

I solved it !
I should have used "RelayCommnad" instead of "ICommnad" like you said.
Thank you so much!!!
